# How to make cut down time for each item in DataList

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql, database

How to make cut down time for each item in DataList , I have code for one item in datalist, but i need for each item displayed in DataList based on the javascript code for cut down time retrived from the database :

**1-items.aspx page:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var leave =<%=seconds %>;
CounterTimer();
var interv=setInterval(CounterTimer,1000);

function CounterTimer()
{
var day = Math.floor(leave / ( 60 * 60 * 24))
var hour = Math.floor(leave / 3600) - (day * 24)
var minute = Math.floor(leave / 60) - (day * 24 *60) - (hour * 60)
var second = Math.floor(leave) - (day * 24 *60*60) - (hour * 60 * 60) - (minute*60)

hour=hour<10 ? "0" + hour : hour;
minute=minute<10 ? "0" + minute : minute;
second=second<10 ? "0" + second : second;

var d=day+" Days";
var h=hour+" H";
var m=minute+" M";
var s=second+" S";
document.getElementById("lbl1").innerText=d;
document.getElementById("lbl2").innerText=h;
document.getElementById("lbl3").innerText=m;
document.getElementById("lbl4").innerText=s;
leave=leave-1;
</script>

 <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="item_id" 
      RepeatColumns="3" 
    RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="100%" ondatabinding="DataList1_DataBinding" 
    >

    <ItemStyle Font-Bold="False" CssClass="data_list_item" />

    <ItemTemplate>
      <div class="thumbnail">
       <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "item_details.aspx?id="+Eval("item_id") %>'>
          <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Bid_Increment") %>' 
              class="label label-important dosis-regular"></asp:Label> 
          <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image") %>' AlternateText='<%# Eval("item_id") %>' Width="220px" Height="175px" />
        <div class="caption">
          <h4><%# Eval("name") %></h4>
       </asp:HyperLink>
          <p>
              <asp:Button ID="btn_biding"  runat="server" Text="Bid" class="btn ad-to" 
                  onclick="btn_biding_Click"  /><span class="price pull-right">  <span>Start price : <%# Eval("intialprice") %> </span></span></p>
      </div>
     <div>
      <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Width="50px" Height="30px"></asp:Label>
      <asp:Label ID="lbl2" runat="server" Width="50px" Height="30px"></asp:Label>
      <asp:Label ID="lbl3" runat="server" Width="50px" Height="30px"></asp:Label>
      <asp:Label ID="lbl4" runat="server" Width="50px" Height="30px"></asp:Label>
     </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" 
        Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" Wrap="False" />
</asp:DataList>
```

2-items.cs code behind:

```
public double seconds;
 SqlConnection con = new        SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AuctionConn"].ToString());
SqlCommand cmd;
SqlDataReader rd;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    seconds = (GetEndTime() - GetStartTime()).TotalSeconds;


}
private DateTime GetStartTime()
{
    return DateTime.Now;
}
private DateTime GetEndTime()
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select endDate from items", con);
    con.Open();
    rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    rd.Read();


    return Convert.ToDateTime(rd["endDate"]);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I have an auction web system , I need display cut down time of the products for each item in GridView or ListView, the above code work for one item in the gridview...                                        see the website : https://www.quibids.com/en/landing/?mb=ogg